# csvread error when loading csv file from root directory

Tags: matlab, csv

Below is the code I am working currently:

```
cd '/Users/K3iTH/Desktop/Ubuntu (Shared)/Trial/'
filename = 'slice_quarter0';
k = 1
inputfile = sprintf('%s.%d.csv','filename',k-1);
data = csvread(inputfile,1,0);
```

I am trying to load the `.csv` file exported in Ubuntu. The code is run until `inputfile`. When I try to run `data = csvread(inputfile,1,0);`, it stated file not found.

Any mistake I did?

Comment: What is the value of the `inputfile` variable when you call `cvsread`? Maybe you don't want the quotes surrounding `filename` in the `sprintf` call?

Comment: @user8153: Yep, that's the problem. Wanna put that in an answer?

Comment: I just posted the same thing, but can take it down if @user8153 wants to instead.

Comment: What you mean by value of inputfile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file *slice_quarter0.csv* exists, and is located in your working directory  then you should modify your sprintf call to

```
inputfile = sprintf('%s%d.csv',filename,k-1);
```

Otherwise, `csvread` will try to open a file named *filename.0.csv*, which will cause the error you have since it presumably does not exist.

Comment: The file slice_quarter0.csv existed in working directory, and I tried

inputfile = sprintf('%s.%d.csv',filename,k-1);

Unfortunately, it still showed file not found.

Comment: Okay, then we need to change the sprintf call further, I'll update.

Comment: Another issue then is the extra `.` between your `%s` and `%d` format modifiers, which you don't want based on your comment.

Comment: Ya, the . between %s and %d is one of the issue. I think I solved by removed %d modifier that caused the filename called different with the file name that I wanted to call. 
Thank you guys.